# Bash - renaming multiple file extensions

Tags: linux, bash

I've just very recently switched to Linux and I want to change a load of files to have different extensions. For example I want to change .doc/docx to .txt and images to .jpg and so on. Is there a csh script that would cover any extension or would I have to write a new one for each filetype.

I have this so far, but I'm not sure if it will actually work. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.$1
do
    [ -f "$f" ] && mv -v "$f" "${f%$1}$2"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would do the rename; keep in mind that renaming a Word document won't cause it to become text, though.

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinvent the wheel:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

```
rename .doc .txt *.doc
```

Answer (score 5):

You need proper programs to convert file format:

- Use [`wvWare`](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/index.html) to convert `doc` to `html`
- Use [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert `png` to `jpg`
- Use [`html2text`](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/) to convert `html` to `txt`